# Translate text used in footer of email

Tags: magento-1.9, php, store-view, localisation, ce-1.9.2.4

I have two store views in my website. I have to translate a text in footer in english and french. How to translate the text used in footer?

Comment: I need to translate the text in 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Create your own theme ( please check this link for create theme : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html ) and in that create below file and also anothet file for french language file :

```
{Magento root}\app\design\frontend\{Your Vendor}\ {Your theme}\Magento_Theme\i18n\en_US.csv
```

in `en_US.csv` file add your text for translate :

```
"Footer","Footer"
```

After above is done please run below command in cmd :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1.9, it's not really much different from the Magento 2 answer provided by user46386. It's just in a different place.

Create your translation files here:

```
{Magento root}/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv
{Magento root}/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv
```

Then fill them in the format below:

```
"Original text","Translated text"
```